# only pg_catalog tables showing in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

when I run this query in redshift:

```
select distinct schemaname, tablename from pg_table_def;
```

I only get pg_catalog schema back and not the user schemas. I'm running the query under the admin user and have also run it under the other user names too but the same thing happens. I dont' get the none system schema's back.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your [search_path](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_search_path.html) user/session parameter lists correctly the wanted schema names.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%pg%'
```

The table information_schema.tabes should help you find all the pg tables